# Is "figure" correct?

Tags: word-usage

Could anyone please tell me if "figure" is natural here? (The figure is meant to be the man the cops are looking for)

> The cops are searching the rooms in the dark hall. As they enter an office, a **figure** emerges from a room at the end of the hall and slips around a corner.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal usage but, used like this, usually refers to someone or something seen indistinctly, certainly not well enough to be identified. For example someone in an old manor house at night might "see the figure of a man" in a dark corridor and, when they get closer find that the figure "resolved itself" into a suit of armour.

The Cambridge Dictionary has [this entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/figure) (go down to B2) which defines "figure" as

> the shape of the human body, or a person: